# Netbeans Visual Library into Eclipse Editors

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

Does anyone know if it is possible to use/embed the Netbeans Visual Library into the a Eclipse Editor in order to develop plugins for Eclipse.

I was taking a look to the GEF Project from Eclipse and I think that Netbeans Visual Library is easier to use than GEF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do that. Anything UI related from Netbeans is going to be Swing-based. Eclipse is SWT-based. Mixing the too UI stacks is possible with SWT-AWT bridge, but there are numerous issues with the bridge. You are far better off learning GEF.